# Callback URL error when setting up webhook for messenger

Tags: python, facebook, bots

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://blog.hartleybrody.com/fb-messenger-bot/) to set a chatbot for messenger. I'm stuck on the webhook setup. I added the page token and verify token to heroku, but when I try to add the heroku URL as the callback URL I get

> The URL couldn't be validated. Callback verification failed with the
>   following errors: HTTP Status Code = 403; HTTP Message = FORBIDDEN

Comment: Do you have to use python? https://github.com/matthewericfisher/fb-robot for a functioning Node JS example.  Running at https://m.me/dynamicmemorysolutions

Comment: Based on the message appears the port is not open or you are using the wrong port.  The Heroku side must be up and running for the validation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN` and `VERIFY_TOKEN` were not set. The tutorial said to use the command `heroku config:add` the correct command should be `heroku config:set`.